# MUI DateField leap year validation activates too early when using AdapterDateFns

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, mui-x

I'm noticing that when I enter a date into a MUI DateField (version 6.4.0 of @mui/x-date-pickers), the validation logic kicks in at a different point depending on the date adapter I'm using (AdapterDateFns vs AdapterDayjs).  It's an edge case, but the issue is that the 29th Feb is reverted to 28th before a full year (potentially a valid leap year) is entered. Some users may not see this date change, and submit an incorrect date.

When populating the DateField with 29th February on a valid leap year, the DateField reverts the day to the 28th after entering the first character of the year e.g. ('1' of 1988) when using AdapterDateFns so it appears to be attempting to validate the date as '29/02/0001' (with 0001 not being a leap year).

The behaviour with AdapterDayjs is different, and retains the date (29th) until a four-digit year has been entered.

Is there a way I can configure AdapterDateDns to behave in the same way as AdapterDayjs?

Date adapter behaviour difference can be seen here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datefield-leap-year-issue-6hj5ys?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

The fix was added in this PR: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/pull/9973
I updated my version of mui/x-date-pickers to "^6.15.0" so that it includes this bugfix, and it seemed to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).